# How to implement angular material mutually exclusive checkable menu items?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

All the examples I found have buttons with either label or icon and label as menu items. Is there an easy way to do the example below taken from material design's [page](https://material.io/design/components/menus.html#anatomy) ?

[image]

I've tried something like this, but it seems really cumbersome way to do it.

TS

```
  icon1 = 'check'
  icon2 = undefined;

  onOptionClick(parameter : string) {
    if (parameter === 'option1') {
      this.icon1 = 'check';
      this.icon2 = undefined;
    }
    else {
      this.icon1 = undefined;
      this.icon2 = 'check';
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
  <button #option1 mat-menu-item (click)="onOptionClick('option1')">
    <mat-icon>{{icon1}}</mat-icon>
    <span>option1</span>
  </button>
  <button #option2 mat-menu-item (click)="onOptionClick('option2')">
    <mat-icon>{{icon2}}</mat-icon>
    <span>option2</span>
  </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a little StackBlitz on how I'd approach this. I'd basically use a [MatButtonToggleGroup](https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/api) and customize it a little bit. Wrap the whole thing in a custom component to make it reusable throughout your application and you're done: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thkwnk

This obviously has a pretty limited design and you would've to extend/adapt it to your needs, f.i. if you needed different values than labels for your options.

Comment: thanks! I check it out now. I edited my question cause I got it to somewhat work.